# Bent Door Hinge & Partially Broken Frame

Tags: hinges

This door was slammed so hard that it flew past the peice of wood that is nailed to the frame and now the hinges are severely bent. The door doesn’t close completely. In fact it now opens in the wrong direction.

I can’t get a screwdriver between the door and the hinges to remove the door  because of how bent the hinges are and the hinges themselves are weird. Neither end has a cap/head and there are little washers in between each section.

This door leads to a bedroom and the more we squeeze in and out of it the hinges bend more and more. I really need a way to fix this. Please help.

[image: This Is what I see from the Outside Of The Door In the hallway]

Comment: You can't remove the hinge from the door by removing the screws?

Comment: No. The hinges are severely bent on the inside, and the door doesn’t close enough from the outside to get leverage to turn the screwdriver.

Comment: And you can't access the hinge screws on the frame side either? Sorry, I'm having trouble visualizing from that picture

Comment: I’m Trying To add more pictures for better reference. Just don’t know how to do that yet.

Comment: Thanks, that helped! It looks like you could remove the frame side hinge screws to me. Have you tried that yet? Also, have you been able to get it to open the correct direction yet? It went one way; it should be able to go back

Comment: For further reference these pictures were taken from inside the room. I’m not quite sure what frame side means. But I Can Get The screwdriver in there But I cant get the leverage to turn it. When I try to it just starts to strip the screw. As far as opening the door the other way I can’t. Since the hinge is no longer flush to the frame, the door leans “off track”. When I try to either push it back or pull it back to the correct side it just bangs into the frame on the outside.

Comment: Just drive the hinge pins out from the bottom. If necessary, cut the hinge leaf that's attached to the door with a reciprocating saw and a fine-toothed blade.

Comment: I Tried Doing That. From The Top And Bottom. They Don’t Have Any Heads/Caps. And They’re Really Old And Rusted. I’ve Been Spraying Dw40 Into The Openings In Hopes Of Loosening It Up To No Avail.

Answer (score 2):

If the door slammed so hard that it squeezed past the door stop then the thing that you will have to do is to remove the door stop so that you can try to wedge the door back to it's correct side of the opening. Once that is achieved you can proceed to replace the hinges with new ones and then finally reinstall the door stop.

This picture shows what I refer to as the door stop molding:

[image]

<sup>*(Picture Source: http://www.agnewtimber.com/12-x-44-pre-primed-whitewood-ogee-door-stop-door-set.php?cat=99)*</sup>

Comment: The hinge is bent too badly It bags into the frame from the other side. Maybe if someone stronger tried pushing it back.?

Comment: Use the door as leverage to bend it back. If it's so bad you can't get to the screws no matter what you try, you may have to cut the hinge off using a reciprocating saw or hack saw. You only need to cut 1. I'd do the bottom.

Comment: Might as well cut the hinges as it looks like they are damaged beyond repair. Keep forcing the door your going to split the wood and cause even more problems.

Comment: Guys I Um...I Don’t Own A Reciprocating Saw, nor Do I Know Anyone Who Does. My parents are 27hrs away and I’m renting this money pit of a mobile home from this elderly couple who stay in Florida. My tuition is killing me and So is my car. I just need a cheap easy way to fix this door. At this point I’m near hysterics and very tempted to just round house kick off the hinges and call it a day.

Comment: @BrokeCollegeChronicles Could a neighbor lend you a hacksaw? Also, if the hinge is bending easily, it might be able to be broken just by repeatedly opening and closing the door as much as it will allow.

Comment: Would lock cutters work. I only have a little hand saw.

Comment: @BrokeCollegeChronicles Bolt cutters should be able to cut it if you can get the positioning.

Comment: Cool. I Actually Have Some Of Those.

Comment: If the bolt cutter doesn't. Since you need this the cheapest way possible, the simplest I can think of to cut it off is to buy a single hack saw blade (less than a dollar). Put a pair of gloves on and then saw it like this.